# Implement Hibernate with OrderBy

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to implement Hibernate query with OrderBy clause. I tried this:

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<OrdersModel> query = builder.createQuery(OrdersModel.class);
        Root<OrdersModel> root = query.from(OrdersModel.class);
        query.select(root).orderBy(root.get("added"));
        Query<OrdersModel> q = session.createQuery(query);

        cdList = q.getResultList();
```

But I have to cast the `.orderBy` like this `query.select(root).orderBy((List<javax.persistence.criteria.Order>) root.get("added"));`

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this?

I tried also this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<OrdersModel> query = builder.createQuery(OrdersModel.class);
            Root<OrdersModel> root = query.from(OrdersModel.class);
            query.select(root);

            query.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("added")));

            Query<OrdersModel> q = session.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(5);

            cdList = q.getResultList();
```

But the rows order are not displayed properly.  The list is not properly sorted.

Comment: What do you mean by *displayed*? When they are displayed in GUI, the order depends on GUI that you use.

Comment: 2nd option seems to be correct. Is the query getting executed successfully and the data not sorted only?